# C++ gRPC bindings in C

Tags: c++, c, grpc, google-assistant-sdk

Is it possible to use the C++ bindings for assistant sdk in a C program?  Right now I am using java for the Google Assistant SDK, but commands for assistant are being generated from a C program, and sent to the java client on a local socket connection.  I am curious if I could integrate this all into a single C program, but I do not know enough about compatibility for C to C++ and vice versa to know if this is feasible.  Thanks.

Comment: In general, if you want to use a C++ library from C, you have to write an API wrapper in C++, exposing `extern "C"` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no. The C++ library needs to have been "designed" to allow for this, with liberal amounts of `extern "C"`s all around. For example, see [Can I use C++ libraries in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658067/can-i-use-c-libraries-in-a-c-program)